# Error while running unit test - Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' from '../../node_modules/ngx-filesaver/fesm2020/ngx-filesaver.mjs'

Tags: angular

We have an Angular app that I recently upgraded to Angular 15 (from Angular 11). After upgrading - running the unit test case we get the following error:

```
    Cannot find module '@angular/common/http' from '../../node_modules/ngx-filesaver/fesm2020/ngx-filesaver.mjs'

    Require stack:
      /<<Path>>/node_modules/ngx-filesaver/fesm2020/ngx-filesaver.mjs
      src/app/utils/utils-service.ts
      src/app/utils/index.ts
      src/app/services/actions-listener.service.ts
```

ng version response is below:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 15.2.10
Node: 18.18.0
Package Manager: npm 9.8.1
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 15.2.10
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1502.10
@angular-devkit/build-angular      15.2.10
@angular-devkit/core               15.2.10
@angular-devkit/schematics         15.2.10
@angular/cdk                       15.2.9
@angular/material                  15.2.9
@angular/material-moment-adapter   15.2.9
@schematics/angular                15.2.10
rxjs                               6.5.5
typescript                         4.9.5
```

Package json has following version of ngx-filesaver:

"ngx-filesaver": "15.0.0",

The Angular project is part of a mono repo. The node_modules in the root folder does not contain the @angular/common but the node_modules of the Angular app does contain the @angular/common folder.

Any pointers on what could be wrong?

I also tried importing HttpClientModule and the FileSaverModule in my main app module but it did not help. It was not required in Angular version 11.

Comment: did you import the commonModule?